# About to start a new project I have some questions before I start

Tags: led-strip, adapter

So I am going to start to build a table that will have two different stands of lights, which are linked below. I was planning on using an 18 volt Milwaukee battery, but after getting the lights, I realized they need AC to work. They both of AC to DC converters that then plug into the light. My first thought was to add an inverter to invert the battery's DC to AC for it to then get inverted back to DC. My questions are;

1. How much power will this lose during inversions
2. Am I better off making my own adapter and not using the wall plug that the lights came with?
   Any advice is apricated!

lights:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08149RHYZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08149RHYZ)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08P25GMCJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08P25GMCJ)

Comment: It would be much easier and efficient to get a DCDC converter module to make 12 V from your battery's 18 V DC and use 12 V LED strips. Maybe these LED strips are actually using 12 V already.

Comment: >> after getting the lights, I realized they need AC to work    --  No they don't.   LED's and the associated digital circuitry are ABSOLUTELY DC devices.  The little AC transformer they included will output 12VDC.  You can throw that piece away.    Try to find 12V batteries if you can... 18V may blow these out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Without knowing the inverter specs and with how non steady the current is on color changing leds we can't tell you how inefficient the setup will be, but it will probably be significant considering you are using a drill battery.
2. Yes. Very much so. Both seem to indicate they use an external AC to 12V DC adapter, to a barrel jack. You can use a switching regulator to bring down the 18v (nominal) to a steady 12V. 11V may be better for a minimal brightness hit but will let the leds live longer. You may also want to get a low voltage lockout circuit so you don't over drain the battery.

You want to check the actual voltage the ac adapter puts out (measure, or just trust the label). The images on the first one indicate it is a single IC per segment and that tends to indicate a 5V led. So be certain.